# How to attach a groupby aggregate to the original dataframe where the aggregate is placed in a new column at the bottom of each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2],'values':np.arange(10,30,5)})`

How can I group by `A` to get the sum of `values`, where the sum is placed in a new column `sum_values_A`, but only once at the bottom of each group. e.g.

```
    A   values  sum_values_A
0   1   10      NaN
1   1   15      25
2   2   20      NaN
3   2   25      45
```

I tried

```
df['sum_values_A'] = df.groupby('A')['values'].transform('sum')

df['sum_values_A'] = df.groupby('A')['sum_values_A'].unique()
```

But couldn't find a way to get the unique sums to be sorted at the bottom of each group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc[~df['A'].duplicated(keep='last'),
       'sum_values_A'
      ] = df.groupby('A')['values'].transform('sum')

print(df)
```

Or:

```
m = ~df['A'].duplicated(keep='last')

df.loc[m, 'sum_values_A'] = df.loc[m, 'A'].map(df.groupby('A')['values'].sum())
```

Output:

```
   A  values  sum_values_A
0  1      10           NaN
1  1      15          25.0
2  2      20           NaN
3  2      25          45.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2],'values':np.arange(10,30,5)})

df = df.assign(sum_values_A=df.groupby('A').cumsum()
               [df['A'].duplicated(keep='first')])
```

```
>>> df
   A  values  sum_values_A
0  1      10           NaN
1  1      15          25.0
2  2      20           NaN
3  2      25          45.0
```